# Tensor product of injective linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, modules, tensor-products

Let $X,Y,U,V$ be vector spaces. Let $S:X\to U$ and $T:Y\to V$ be linear maps. Then by linearisation there exists a linear map
$$S\otimes T : X\otimes Y \to U\otimes V,\quad x\otimes y \mapsto (Sx) \otimes (Ty). $$ 
If $S$ and $T$ are injective, then their tensor product is, too. I think I managed to justify this as follows.

Note that $U = S(X) \oplus U'$. Define $S' : U\to X$ such that $S'(S(x_u) +u' ) = x_u$. One readily verifies linearity and that is a left inverse for $S$. Analogously, define $T':V\to Y$. Then by linearisation, there exists linear
$$S'\otimes T' : U\otimes V \to X\otimes Y,\quad (S(x_u)+u') \otimes (T(y_v) + v') \mapsto x_u\otimes y_v. $$
This would give a left inverse for $S\otimes T$ hence making it injective.

---

I seem to recall that tensoring injective morphisms between modules does not always preserve injectivity. In fact, a certain module $F$ for which $\mbox{id}_F \otimes \phi$ is injective for all injective morphisms $\phi$ is called flat.

> What am I invoking here that allows this to work for vector spaces?

Is it the decomposition $U=S(X) \oplus U'$?

Comment: I think it is simplier by considering the kernel. If $a \otimes b =0$, then you have $a=0$ or $b=0$ (as you are working over a field), so if you have $Sx \otimes Ty=0$ it follows that $Sx=0$ or $Ty=0$.

Comment: @Matthias uh, I was hoping $a\otimes b \Rightarrow a= 0 \lor b=0$ holds, I didn't find any way to justify it, though, so I had to use a cannon..

Comment: A way to see that (even though not the most beautiful way I think) is the following: If $(e_i)_{i \in I}, (f_j)_{j \in J}$ is a basis for A, respectively B, you know that $(e_i \otimes f_j)_{(i,j) \in I \times J}$ is a basis for their tensor product. Now express everything with respect to that basis.

Comment: I do not understand your calculation. Go the other way round and write $x= \sum_{i=0}^n \lambda_i e_i$ and $y=\sum_{j=0}^m \gamma_j f_j$ and assume their tensor product is 0.

Comment: @Matthias in that case
$$0 = x\otimes y = (\sum _{i=1}^n\lambda _ie_i) \otimes (\sum _{j=1}^m\mu _j f_j) = \sum _{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m \lambda _i\mu _j (e_i\otimes f_j) $$
Ok, linear independence implies the coefficients are zero, but how do we know that $x=0$ or $y=0$ precisely? If $n=m$, then we can have alternating between zero and non-zero and this equality is still satisfied. Kind of like
 $$(1,0) \cdot (0,1) = 0 $$
but neither vector is zero.

Comment: This cannot occur, as all(!) possible combinations of the form $\lambda_i \gamma_j$ have to be zero. To see this, just use some formal logic.

Comment: @Matthias oh yes, I see, if any $\lambda _i \neq 0$, then all the $\mu _j$ are forced to be zero. Silly mistake by me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know, this is an old question, but I both hate it when questions are solely answered within the comments, and I think the crucial term has not been named yet:

For a field $\mathbb{K}$, vector spaces over $\mathbb{K}$ are the same as **free** $\mathbb{K}$-modules! Freeness means exactly that they admit a basis, and it implies the flatness as $\mathbb{K}$-modules. Of course, the proof for this goes exactly as it was explained in the comments. It is an important and useful property to keep in mind.